# error with JTable - while inserting JComboBox (DateComboBox)

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox, tablecelleditor

I have a dateComboBox (works PERFECT), I implemented it on a JTable:

The result is as I want. Once the user clicks on the 2nd column, the DateComboBox is open and the user can click on the desired date. HOWEVER, for some reason, once the user clicks on that date it doesn't appear in the cell?

The cells are editable (so as the dateComboBox) so if he TYPES something else (string, int, ...) it works great.

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: Please, post your code, to allow us find the problem

Comment: to expand on @MaximShoustin's comment: .. your code in form of a SSCCE :-)